# Formatting in percent by Intl.NumberFormat in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, format, number-formatting

```js
var discount = 25.1;

var option = {
  style: 'percent',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
};
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', option);
var discountFormat = formatter.format(discount);

console.log(discountFormat)
```

While I want you to come back like this: `25.10%`

Comment: harcdoded 'en-US'.... Typical...

Answer (score 49):

Because `25.1` is `2510%`. Percentages are fractions of `100`. If you had 100% it would be `100/100` which is equal to 1. So `25.1%` is `25/100` or `0.251` not `25.1`

```js
var discount = 0.251;

var option = {
  style: 'percent',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
};

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", option);
var discountFormat = formatter.format(discount);

console.log(discountFormat);
```

Also if you wanted to keep the trailing zero you would need to set `minimumFractionDigits` as the default for percentages is `0`.

If your value is the actual percentage to be displayed, you would just put the `%` symbol on the end, eg `value = 25.1+"0%";`.

Answer (score 4):

or you can use Arrow function

```
const percentageFormatter = intl = value => intl.formateNumber(value/100, {
style: "percent",
maximumFractionDigits:2
}
```

if you want to use for field as a percentage field with "%" suffix.
or else

```
const Num = 3223;
const CurrencyFormatter = intl => intl.formateNumber(intl.locale, {
style: "percent",
maximumFractionDigits:2
}
```

### console.log(CurrencyFormatter (Num));

```py
If you wan to use the locale for the currency symbol you can make use of {toLocaleString}
```

```
export const currencyFormatWithLocale = (value, locale) => {
  const currency = currencyToLocale[locale];
  return (
    !!value &&
    value.toLocaleString(`${locale}`, {
      style: "currency",
      currency: currency
    })
  );
};

/* To be updated based on need - French - Canada and US locale handled  */
export const currencyToLocale = {
  "fr-CA": "CAD",
  "hi-IND": "INR",
  "en-US": "USD"
};
```